# What is the definition of latin1 character set in MySQL 8.0 and MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, character-set, utf-8

I am trying to fix some corruption to character fields in my database after a migration. I suspect that part of the problem is that fields with UTF-8 data were interpreted with the MySQL `latin1` character set. Before I try to fix the problem, I want to understand it. Part of that is to understand exactly what the `latin1` character set is.

What is the formal definition of mapping between code points (byte values) and characters for the `latin1` character set in MySQL 8.0, and in MySQL 5.7? If collation matters, I will take the answer for `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.

`latin1` is said to be identical to the [Windows CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. In the Wikipedia article on CP-1252, there is a table of 256 byte code values, with a character in each cell of the table. That is the sort of definition I am after. But, I am hoping for something more rigorous than "it's the same as CP-1252" and "that table in Wikipedia is probably accurate".

I have tried looking through the MySQL documentation. I hoped that [10.10.2 *West European Character Sets*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-we-sets.html) would like to the formal definition, but I do not see it there. Nor do I see an answer here, or on Wikipedia.

If there is a MySQL source file which defines `latin1`, and I can view that source file via a URL, that might well be good enough.  But if someone has made up a 256-cell table, that is even better.

Comment: There is a comment in the MySQL source code explaining their encoding here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/strings/ctype-latin1.cc#L115-L135 and arrays which I infer map the code points to other encodings, but I don't understand how they are used.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thank you for the link. It might be helpful for a question about, "how do I fix the corruption?", but this question is "what is the definition of latin1?".

Comment: @BillKarwin Congratulations! The link you give to the MySQL source appears to be the core of a definitive answer, because it shows exactly how MySQL interprets Latin1 code units (byte values) in terms of Unicode characters. Make it an answer, and I'll upvote it. Add in a description of how to interpret the code, and I'll accept it as the correct answer. Good work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find a specification, one way to answer the question is to test the system. The following query generates code units (byte values) from `00` to `FF`, interprets them as characters using the `latin1` encoding, then delivers a table of the code unit, the character, the Unicode scalar value (which one can look up in [The Unicode Standard's character code charts](https://unicode.org/charts/)), and the UTF-8 code units (bytes):

```sql
with 
recursive code_units(code) as (
    select 0 as 'code'
    union all 
    select code+1 from code_units where code < 255
),
latin1_repertoire(code, char_latin1, unicode_scalar, utf8mb4_code_units) as (
    select 
        code, 
        char(code USING 'latin1'), 
        convert(char(code USING 'latin1') using 'utf32'), 
        convert(char(code USING 'latin1') using 'utf8mb4')
    from code_units
)
select
    hex(char_latin1) as 'latin1 hex', 
    concat('U-',right(hex(unicode_scalar),6)) as 'Unicode scalar',
    hex(utf8mb4_code_units) as 'utf-8 hex',
    char_latin1 as 'latin1 char' 
from latin1_repertoire;
```

Here is what I get when I run this query on my copy of MySQL 8.0.30:

```
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| latin1 hex | Unicode scalar | utf-8 hex | latin1 char |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| 00         | U-000000       | 00        |             |
| 01         | U-000001       | 01        |            |
| 02         | U-000002       | 02        |            |
| 03         | U-000003       | 03        |            |
| 04         | U-000004       | 04        |            |
| 05         | U-000005       | 05        |            |
| 06         | U-000006       | 06        |            |
| 07         | U-000007       | 07        |            |
| 08         | U-000008       | 08        |           |
| 09         | U-000009       | 09        |                |
| 0A         | U-00000A       | 0A        | 
           |
| 0B         | U-00000B       | 0B        | 
                                                       |
| 0C         | U-00000C       | 0C        | 
                                                       |
           | | U-00000D       | 0D        | 
| 0E         | U-00000E       | 0E        |            |
| 0F         | U-00000F       | 0F        |            |
| 10         | U-000010       | 10        |            |
| 11         | U-000011       | 11        |            |
| 12         | U-000012       | 12        |            |
| 13         | U-000013       | 13        |            |
| 14         | U-000014       | 14        |            |
| 15         | U-000015       | 15        |            |
| 16         | U-000016       | 16        |            |
| 17         | U-000017       | 17        |            |
| 18         | U-000018       | 18        |            |
| 19         | U-000019       | 19        |            |
| 1A         | U-00001A       | 1A        |            |
| 1B         | U-00001B       | 1B        |           |
| 1C         | U-00001C       | 1C        |            |
| 1D         | U-00001D       | 1D        |            |
| 1E         | U-00001E       | 1E        |            |
| 1F         | U-00001F       | 1F        |            |
| 20         | U-000020       | 20        |             |
| 21         | U-000021       | 21        | !           |
| 22         | U-000022       | 22        | "           |
| 23         | U-000023       | 23        | #           |
| 24         | U-000024       | 24        | $           |
| 25         | U-000025       | 25        | %           |
| 26         | U-000026       | 26        | &           |
| 27         | U-000027       | 27        | '           |
| 28         | U-000028       | 28        | (           |
| 29         | U-000029       | 29        | )           |
| 2A         | U-00002A       | 2A        | *           |
| 2B         | U-00002B       | 2B        | +           |
| 2C         | U-00002C       | 2C        | ,           |
| 2D         | U-00002D       | 2D        | -           |
| 2E         | U-00002E       | 2E        | .           |
| 2F         | U-00002F       | 2F        | /           |
| 30         | U-000030       | 30        | 0           |
| 31         | U-000031       | 31        | 1           |
| 32         | U-000032       | 32        | 2           |
| 33         | U-000033       | 33        | 3           |
| 34         | U-000034       | 34        | 4           |
| 35         | U-000035       | 35        | 5           |
| 36         | U-000036       | 36        | 6           |
| 37         | U-000037       | 37        | 7           |
| 38         | U-000038       | 38        | 8           |
| 39         | U-000039       | 39        | 9           |
| 3A         | U-00003A       | 3A        | :           |
| 3B         | U-00003B       | 3B        | ;           |
| 3C         | U-00003C       | 3C        | <           |
| 3D         | U-00003D       | 3D        | =           |
| 3E         | U-00003E       | 3E        | >           |
| 3F         | U-00003F       | 3F        | ?           |
| 40         | U-000040       | 40        | @           |
| 41         | U-000041       | 41        | A           |
| 42         | U-000042       | 42        | B           |
| 43         | U-000043       | 43        | C           |
| 44         | U-000044       | 44        | D           |
| 45         | U-000045       | 45        | E           |
| 46         | U-000046       | 46        | F           |
| 47         | U-000047       | 47        | G           |
| 48         | U-000048       | 48        | H           |
| 49         | U-000049       | 49        | I           |
| 4A         | U-00004A       | 4A        | J           |
| 4B         | U-00004B       | 4B        | K           |
| 4C         | U-00004C       | 4C        | L           |
| 4D         | U-00004D       | 4D        | M           |
| 4E         | U-00004E       | 4E        | N           |
| 4F         | U-00004F       | 4F        | O           |
| 50         | U-000050       | 50        | P           |
| 51         | U-000051       | 51        | Q           |
| 52         | U-000052       | 52        | R           |
| 53         | U-000053       | 53        | S           |
| 54         | U-000054       | 54        | T           |
| 55         | U-000055       | 55        | U           |
| 56         | U-000056       | 56        | V           |
| 57         | U-000057       | 57        | W           |
| 58         | U-000058       | 58        | X           |
| 59         | U-000059       | 59        | Y           |
| 5A         | U-00005A       | 5A        | Z           |
| 5B         | U-00005B       | 5B        | [           |
| 5C         | U-00005C       | 5C        | \           |
| 5D         | U-00005D       | 5D        | ]           |
| 5E         | U-00005E       | 5E        | ^           |
| 5F         | U-00005F       | 5F        | _           |
| 60         | U-000060       | 60        | `           |
| 61         | U-000061       | 61        | a           |
| 62         | U-000062       | 62        | b           |
| 63         | U-000063       | 63        | c           |
| 64         | U-000064       | 64        | d           |
| 65         | U-000065       | 65        | e           |
| 66         | U-000066       | 66        | f           |
| 67         | U-000067       | 67        | g           |
| 68         | U-000068       | 68        | h           |
| 69         | U-000069       | 69        | i           |
| 6A         | U-00006A       | 6A        | j           |
| 6B         | U-00006B       | 6B        | k           |
| 6C         | U-00006C       | 6C        | l           |
| 6D         | U-00006D       | 6D        | m           |
| 6E         | U-00006E       | 6E        | n           |
| 6F         | U-00006F       | 6F        | o           |
| 70         | U-000070       | 70        | p           |
| 71         | U-000071       | 71        | q           |
| 72         | U-000072       | 72        | r           |
| 73         | U-000073       | 73        | s           |
| 74         | U-000074       | 74        | t           |
| 75         | U-000075       | 75        | u           |
| 76         | U-000076       | 76        | v           |
| 77         | U-000077       | 77        | w           |
| 78         | U-000078       | 78        | x           |
| 79         | U-000079       | 79        | y           |
| 7A         | U-00007A       | 7A        | z           |
| 7B         | U-00007B       | 7B        | {           |
| 7C         | U-00007C       | 7C        | |           |
| 7D         | U-00007D       | 7D        | }           |
| 7E         | U-00007E       | 7E        | ~           |
| 7F         | U-00007F       | 7F        |            |
| 80         | U-0020AC       | E282AC    | €           |
| 81         | U-000081       | C281      |            |
| 82         | U-00201A       | E2809A    | ‚           |
| 83         | U-000192       | C692      | ƒ           |
| 84         | U-00201E       | E2809E    | „           |
| 85         | U-002026       | E280A6    | …           |
| 86         | U-002020       | E280A0    | †           |
| 87         | U-002021       | E280A1    | ‡           |
| 88         | U-0002C6       | CB86      | ˆ           |
| 89         | U-002030       | E280B0    | ‰           |
| 8A         | U-000160       | C5A0      | Š           |
| 8B         | U-002039       | E280B9    | ‹           |
| 8C         | U-000152       | C592      | Œ           |
| 8D         | U-00008D       | C28D      |            |
| 8E         | U-00017D       | C5BD      | Ž           |
| 8F         | U-00008F       | C28F      |            |
| 90         | U-000090       | C290      |            |
| 91         | U-002018       | E28098    | ‘           |
| 92         | U-002019       | E28099    | ’           |
| 93         | U-00201C       | E2809C    | “           |
| 94         | U-00201D       | E2809D    | ”           |
| 95         | U-002022       | E280A2    | •           |
| 96         | U-002013       | E28093    | –           |
| 97         | U-002014       | E28094    | —           |
| 98         | U-0002DC       | CB9C      | ˜           |
| 99         | U-002122       | E284A2    | ™           |
| 9A         | U-000161       | C5A1      | š           |
| 9B         | U-00203A       | E280BA    | ›           |
| 9C         | U-000153       | C593      | œ           |
| 9D         | U-00009D       | C29D      |            |
| 9E         | U-00017E       | C5BE      | ž           |
| 9F         | U-000178       | C5B8      | Ÿ           |
| A0         | U-0000A0       | C2A0      |             |
| A1         | U-0000A1       | C2A1      | ¡           |
| A2         | U-0000A2       | C2A2      | ¢           |
| A3         | U-0000A3       | C2A3      | £           |
| A4         | U-0000A4       | C2A4      | ¤           |
| A5         | U-0000A5       | C2A5      | ¥           |
| A6         | U-0000A6       | C2A6      | ¦           |
| A7         | U-0000A7       | C2A7      | §           |
| A8         | U-0000A8       | C2A8      | ¨           |
| A9         | U-0000A9       | C2A9      | ©           |
| AA         | U-0000AA       | C2AA      | ª           |
| AB         | U-0000AB       | C2AB      | «           |
| AC         | U-0000AC       | C2AC      | ¬           |
| AD         | U-0000AD       | C2AD      | ­           |
| AE         | U-0000AE       | C2AE      | ®           |
| AF         | U-0000AF       | C2AF      | ¯           |
| B0         | U-0000B0       | C2B0      | °           |
| B1         | U-0000B1       | C2B1      | ±           |
| B2         | U-0000B2       | C2B2      | ²           |
| B3         | U-0000B3       | C2B3      | ³           |
| B4         | U-0000B4       | C2B4      | ´           |
| B5         | U-0000B5       | C2B5      | µ           |
| B6         | U-0000B6       | C2B6      | ¶           |
| B7         | U-0000B7       | C2B7      | ·           |
| B8         | U-0000B8       | C2B8      | ¸           |
| B9         | U-0000B9       | C2B9      | ¹           |
| BA         | U-0000BA       | C2BA      | º           |
| BB         | U-0000BB       | C2BB      | »           |
| BC         | U-0000BC       | C2BC      | ¼           |
| BD         | U-0000BD       | C2BD      | ½           |
| BE         | U-0000BE       | C2BE      | ¾           |
| BF         | U-0000BF       | C2BF      | ¿           |
| C0         | U-0000C0       | C380      | À           |
| C1         | U-0000C1       | C381      | Á           |
| C2         | U-0000C2       | C382      | Â           |
| C3         | U-0000C3       | C383      | Ã           |
| C4         | U-0000C4       | C384      | Ä           |
| C5         | U-0000C5       | C385      | Å           |
| C6         | U-0000C6       | C386      | Æ           |
| C7         | U-0000C7       | C387      | Ç           |
| C8         | U-0000C8       | C388      | È           |
| C9         | U-0000C9       | C389      | É           |
| CA         | U-0000CA       | C38A      | Ê           |
| CB         | U-0000CB       | C38B      | Ë           |
| CC         | U-0000CC       | C38C      | Ì           |
| CD         | U-0000CD       | C38D      | Í           |
| CE         | U-0000CE       | C38E      | Î           |
| CF         | U-0000CF       | C38F      | Ï           |
| D0         | U-0000D0       | C390      | Ð           |
| D1         | U-0000D1       | C391      | Ñ           |
| D2         | U-0000D2       | C392      | Ò           |
| D3         | U-0000D3       | C393      | Ó           |
| D4         | U-0000D4       | C394      | Ô           |
| D5         | U-0000D5       | C395      | Õ           |
| D6         | U-0000D6       | C396      | Ö           |
| D7         | U-0000D7       | C397      | ×           |
| D8         | U-0000D8       | C398      | Ø           |
| D9         | U-0000D9       | C399      | Ù           |
| DA         | U-0000DA       | C39A      | Ú           |
| DB         | U-0000DB       | C39B      | Û           |
| DC         | U-0000DC       | C39C      | Ü           |
| DD         | U-0000DD       | C39D      | Ý           |
| DE         | U-0000DE       | C39E      | Þ           |
| DF         | U-0000DF       | C39F      | ß           |
| E0         | U-0000E0       | C3A0      | à           |
| E1         | U-0000E1       | C3A1      | á           |
| E2         | U-0000E2       | C3A2      | â           |
| E3         | U-0000E3       | C3A3      | ã           |
| E4         | U-0000E4       | C3A4      | ä           |
| E5         | U-0000E5       | C3A5      | å           |
| E6         | U-0000E6       | C3A6      | æ           |
| E7         | U-0000E7       | C3A7      | ç           |
| E8         | U-0000E8       | C3A8      | è           |
| E9         | U-0000E9       | C3A9      | é           |
| EA         | U-0000EA       | C3AA      | ê           |
| EB         | U-0000EB       | C3AB      | ë           |
| EC         | U-0000EC       | C3AC      | ì           |
| ED         | U-0000ED       | C3AD      | í           |
| EE         | U-0000EE       | C3AE      | î           |
| EF         | U-0000EF       | C3AF      | ï           |
| F0         | U-0000F0       | C3B0      | ð           |
| F1         | U-0000F1       | C3B1      | ñ           |
| F2         | U-0000F2       | C3B2      | ò           |
| F3         | U-0000F3       | C3B3      | ó           |
| F4         | U-0000F4       | C3B4      | ô           |
| F5         | U-0000F5       | C3B5      | õ           |
| F6         | U-0000F6       | C3B6      | ö           |
| F7         | U-0000F7       | C3B7      | ÷           |
| F8         | U-0000F8       | C3B8      | ø           |
| F9         | U-0000F9       | C3B9      | ù           |
| FA         | U-0000FA       | C3BA      | ú           |
| FB         | U-0000FB       | C3BB      | û           |
| FC         | U-0000FC       | C3BC      | ü           |
| FD         | U-0000FD       | C3BD      | ý           |
| FE         | U-0000FE       | C3BE      | þ           |
| FF         | U-0000FF       | C3BF      | ÿ           |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
256 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't correctly tell MySQL the encoding of the *client*, various forms of gibberish -- Mojibake, truncation, question marks, etc -- can occur.  For help in that area, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  For "corruption", I recommend starting with that.

Will this table here suffice for seeing the mapping between latin1 and UTF-8; it's the top 128 of your "256-cell table"?
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings
It has columns for decimal, latin1 hex, utf8 hex, the printable character, htmlentity.  Search the web for "ascii"; there are a zillion pages that show the bottom 28.

It is not a formal definition; I sometimes use it as a crutch in answering questions on this forum.

URLs should be encoded with PHP's `urlencode()` (or equivalent), which turns 8-bit codes into 3 characters: '%' plus two hex chars.

As for `latinx` versus `CPxxxx`, there seem to be a very few characters that do not exactly match; usually in the 8x or 9x range.  "Its the same" has been good enough, since the main differences (eg `216 D8 C398 Ø &Oslash;`) is quite glaring.

UTF-8 was being invented before the Euro became a standard currency.  Hence "80" used to be (and may still be) a point of difference: `128 80 E282AC € &#x80;`  Note the 3-byte UTF-8 encoding.

I often run into Microsoft Word documents spitting out an odd space `160 A0 C2A0   &nbsp;`.  Hex 20 is an ordinary space. Turn on the high bit and you get `A0`, which seems to equate to HTML's `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space).  A UTF-8 parser spits at a plain `A0`, but is happy with its equivalent, `C2A0`.

Comment: Upvoted for the link to the chart of the top 128 characters. It looks like a helpful crutch. Thank you! 
I agree that the bottom 128 characters are the same as ASCII and charts for them abound. In fact, the Wikipedia article on CP-1252 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 is as good a chart of the bottom 128 as any. 
I don't fully agree with other details in your answer, but they are off the topic of my question about MySQL 'latin1' anyway.